# pytest.raises passes with wrong exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, pytest

In the following example, I'd expect the test to fail when `expecting` = `NotImplementedError`.

```
import pytest
def fun():
    raise ValueError()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expecting", [
    (ValueError),
    (NotImplementedError)
])
def test_something( expecting):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        fun()
```

But, instead it passes:

```
test_something[ValueError] PASSED
test_something[NotImplementedError] PASSED
```

Why this behavior, and what is the correct usage?

Comment: wow this community can be harsh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test isn't doing anything with `expecting`.  You wrote `with pytest.raises(ValueError):`, so pytest is always looking for a `ValueError`, which is what `fun()` raises.  Perhaps you meant to write `with pytest.raises(expecting):` instead?

Comment: thanks i totally missed that .. i was following pytest examples